# How to use a list<string> as the keys in a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary where the keys will be the elements in a pre-existing `List<string>` and the values will be `List<List<string>>` like this:

```
List<string> newDictKeys = new List<string>(new []{"12323","432234","45345435"});
List<string> listVal1 = new List<string>(new []{"dfgdfg","asdfds","wertert"});
List<string> listVal2 = new List<string>(new []{"ZCxzcx","xcvbcvb","gfhjfgj"});

List<List<string>> dictVals = new List<List<string>>();

Dictionary<string,List<List<string>> dict = new  Dictionary<string,List<List<string>>();
```

Is there any simple, elegant way to do this?

### EDIT

Essentially this would be the mapping:

```
"12323" -> ["dfgdfg","ZCxzcx"]
"432234" -> ["asdfds","xcvbcvb"]
"45345435" -> ["wertert","gfhjfgj"]
```

Comment: for loop would be simple..

Comment: You need to use an `IEqualityComparer` in the constructor of your `Dictionary` for this purpose since you can not override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method in your `List<string>`.

Comment: do you want the _same_ values for each key? Or will you have a bunch of `List<List<string>>` objects that you need to map to each key in `newDictKeys`?

Comment: @JohnM.Wright I just updated the post with clarification

Comment: After your edit, it looks like you want only one item in each sub-list of the values?  Or do you just want the values to be a collection of the nth item in each `listVal` collection?

Comment: @JohnM.Wright Yes, each sub list should only have one value, so there actually wouldn't be a need for lists as SouXin pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You will have two lists stored for the same key why not to combine two lists together?

```
   List<string> newDictKeys  = new List<string>{ "12323", "432234", "45345435"};

    List<string> t = new List<string> { "dfgdfg", "asdfds", "wertert" };
    List<string> t2 = new List<string>{ "ZCxzcx", "xcvbcvb", "gfhjfgj" };
    t.AddRange(t2);

    Dictionary<string,List<string>> dict = newDictKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => t);
```

**UPDATE**

With the list of objects:

```
    List<string> newDictKeys = new List<string> { "12323", "432234", "45345435" };

    List<string> t = new List<string> { "dfgdfg", "asdfds", "wertert" };
    List<string> t2 = new List<string> { "ZCxzcx", "xcvbcvb", "gfhjfgj" };


    Dictionary<string, List<object>> dict = newDictKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => new List<object> {t, t2});
```

**UPDATE 2**
This should make a trick:

```
    List<string> newDictKeys = new List<string> { "12323", "432234", "45345435" };

    List<string> t = new List<string> { "dfgdfg", "asdfds", "wertert" };
    List<string> t2 = new List<string> { "ZCxzcx", "xcvbcvb", "gfhjfgj" };


    Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    foreach (var key in newDictKeys.Where(key => t.Count > 0 && t2.Count > 0))
    {
        dict.Add(key, new List<string> {t.FirstOrDefault(), t2.FirstOrDefault()});
        t.RemoveAt(0);
        t2.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**
With Queue

```
    List<string> newDictKeys = new List<string> { "12323", "432234", "45345435" };

    Queue<string> t = new Queue<string> (new []{ "dfgdfg", "asdfds", "wertert" });
    Queue<string> t2 = new Queue<string>(new[] { "ZCxzcx", "xcvbcvb", "gfhjfgj" });


    Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = newDictKeys
    .Where(key => t.Count > 0 && t2.Count > 0)
    .ToDictionary(key => key, key => new List<string> {t.Dequeue(), t2.Dequeue()});
```

Comment: are you extending list t with list t2?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just so your update. But not sure purpose of that?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to do it like that. What I need is for list t and t2 to be separate and be mapped together collectively to each index in newDictKeys

Comment: If it is new application I would suggest to use List of objects.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my original edit. I just updated again. Was this the understanding you originally had?

Comment: What is the `RemoveAt()` for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154480/discussion-between-souxin-and-loremipsum1771).

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer based on question update**
Ok, so you want the nth item from each value list as the values, which would look like this:

```
List<string> newDictKeys = new List<string>(new []{"12323","432234","45345435"});
List<string> listVal1 = new List<string>(new []{"dfgdfg","asdfds","wertert"});
List<string> listVal2 = new List<string>(new []{"ZCxzcx","xcvbcvb","gfhjfgj"});

List<List<string>> dictVals = new List<List<string>>();
dictVals.Add(listVal1);
dictVals.Add(listVal2);

Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = 
    newDictKeys.Select((key, index) => new {key, index})
               .ToDictionary(entry => entry.key, 
                             entry => new List<string>(){dictVals[0][entry.index], dictVals[1][entry.index]});
```

Basically, it iterates through all the keys in `newDictKeys`, creates a temporary anonymous object with the key and the index of that key into the `newDictKeys` list (so `{"12323", 0}, {"432234", 1}, ...`). Then, it creates a Dictionary where the key is the value from `newDictKeys` and for the value it gets the values from each sub-list in `dictValues` at the same index location.

Or, a simplified version (directly access the `listVal1` and `listVal2` collections instead of `dictVals`:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = 
    newDictKeys.Select((key, index) => new {key, index})
               .ToDictionary(entry => entry.key, 
                             entry => new List<string>(){listVal1[entry.index], listVal2[entry.index]});
```

**Original Answer**
If you want the same set of values for each entry in `newDictKeys`, you could map it like this:

```
List<string> newDictKeys = new List<string>(new []{"12323","432234","45345435"});
List<string> listVal1 = new List<string>(new []{"dfgdfg","asdfds","wertert"});
List<string> listVal2 = new List<string>(new []{"ZCxzcx","xcvbcvb","gfhjfgj"});

List<List<string>> dictVals = new List<List<string>>();
dictVals.Add(listVal1);
dictVals.Add(listVal2);

Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> dict = 
    newDictKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => dictVals);
```

If you want a different set of values for each entry in `newDictKeys`, put the values into an array as well, so that they are in the same order as the keys, you could use `.Select()` to get the index of the key in the key list and then `.ToDictionary()` to map to the values you want, like this:

```
var valuesArray = new []{dictVals, dictVals2, ...};

Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> dict = 
    newDictKeys.Select((key, index) => new {key, index})
               .ToDictionary(entry => entry.key, entry => valuesArray[entry.index]);
```

The `valuesArray` could also be a list, as long as it's values can be retrieved by an indexer.

Comment: Is the `.Select()` needed if I just need each element of newDictKeys to map to the collection of listVal1 and listVal2?

Comment: If every key will have the same values, then you could just do `newDictKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => dictVals);`

Comment: The `.Select()` is only needed to get the index in order to do the lookup to some other storage.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my explanation in the edit. I just updated it again. Would you original solution have worked for that?

Comment: Then you gonna have list of string and not list of list of string right?

Comment: @SouXin You're right, I wouldn't need the list of lists. Just list of two strings

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 ok, I updated it again based on the newest changes.

Comment: @SouXin where?  The `.ToDictionary()` will return a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, which is what _i think_ is being asked for. (The question has changed enough times now that I'm not sure I understand what's actually being asked)

Comment: No, I mean you can do it without dictVal but it will complicate the code. It was a joke. )

Comment: :)  Well, we could always throw some `.ToList()` and `.ToArray()` calls in there, just to make sure we're using all the CPU cores!

Comment: Ok, so this iterates through both listVal1 and listVal2 taking out the current elements in both lists and then puts them in the dictionary at the current key? Sorry, I'm still new to linq

Comment: The original lists aren't modified, so it's nothing is "taken out", just retrieved.  Basically, it iterates through all the keys in `newDictKeys`, creates a temporary anonymous object with the key and the index of that key into the `newDictKeys` list (so `{"12323", 0}, {"432234", 1}, ...`). Then, it creates a Dictionary where the key is the value from `newDictKeys` and for the value it gets the values from each sub-list in `dictValues` at the same index location)

Comment: I just added a slightly simpler version that does away with the `dictVals` collection and just uses `listVals1` and `listVals2` directly.